# File is not being read correctly

Tags: python, file, dictionary, readline

I'm trying to read a file and then store it into a dictionary with year as the key. However, when I read the file, it skips a bunch of lines at a time. The file contains all world series winners (1903-2014).

```
fileName = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    with open(fileName) as f:
        for data in f:
            data = f.readline().strip("\n")
            print(data) ##used to test to make sure the data is being read 
except:
    print("file doesnt exist")
```

The output after running:

```
1905,New York Giants
1907,Chicago Cubs
1909,Pittsburgh Pirates
1911,Philadelphia Athletics
1913,Philadelphia Athletics
1915,Boston Red Sox
1917,Chicago White Sox
...
```

The file

```
1903,Boston Americans
1905,New York Giants
1906,Chicago White Sox
1907,Chicago Cubs
1908,Chicago Cubs
1909,Pittsburgh Pirates
```

Comment: Can you post the file snippet? You are skipping every even entry `(6,8...)` which could mean one line has 2 entries in it

Comment: looks like you are reading a csv file. why not just use the `csv` module?

Answer (score 5):

```
for data in f:
```

already iterates through each line which means:

```
data = f.readline().strip("\n")
```

is not only redundant, it will skip a line and set `data` to equal to whatever the next line is. take that line out

Answer (score 0):

```
print dict(x.split(",") for x in open("filename.txt"))
```

that is all

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module

```
import csv

fileName = input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fileName) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print(dict(reader))
```